# Discord Bot isn't Activating

Tags: python, ssl, discord, bots

I am trying to run my discord bot but then I keep on getting:

```
raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: 
Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

my code is

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hey")

client.run("-------------------------------------")
```

Comment: it is problem with SSL - maybe you have to install newer [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/). It is not Python module but C/C++ library used by many programs to connect with internet using `SSL` - and Python also use it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start, type internet explorer. Run as admin.

Go do https://discord.com click on the padlock icon.

Click view certificates

Click install certificates, choose either user or local machine.

Click Place all certificates in the following store

Choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Enjoy.